# How to add iCloud key-value save feature to a Unity project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, icloud, icloud-api

Since the saved data in PlayerPrefs and PresistentPaths get deleted when a user uninstalls the app i want the game progress to be stored on iCloud.

How to do this in Unity. There are no tutorials on this. Can anyone provide a step by step guide to implement this feature for a Unity project.

Any help would be much appreciated.